# re-update sql trouble

Tags: mysql, sql

I just this error when Im updating database and I dont change any of the values in the form and submit. I would like to know why and suggestion to correct this error.

sample

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 1

  id    =  1,
 name   = John,
 city   = New York;

UPDATE `table` SET name = 'John', city = 'New York' WHERE id = 1
```

when updating the database with the same values what you select from database and use affected rows i get 0

Comment: when updating the database with the same values what you select from database and use affected rows i get 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) states:

> For [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed. If you specify the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag to [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-real-connect.html) when connecting to [*`mysqld`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html), the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the `WHERE` clause.

Therefore, because your `UPDATE` does not actually change any rows, the default affected-rows value is 0.

Comment: how to connect using mysql_real_connect in php??

Comment: @user1358505: If you're using the MySQLi extension, the seventh argument to [`mysqli_real_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) can be set to `MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS`; if using PDO, you can specify the [`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) driver option.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the string values in quotes (')

```
UPDATE `table` SET name = 'John', city = 'New York' WHERE id = 1
```